# Javascript: "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to use the easyPaginate.js plugin (https://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/) in my code:

index.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/myJs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>
...
<div id="easyPaginate">
    <img src="img/demo/surf1.jpg" />
    <img src="img/demo/surf2.jpg" />
</div>
```

myJs.js:

```
$('#easyPaginate').easyPaginate({
    paginateElement: 'img',
    elementsPerPage: 3,
    effect: 'climb'
});
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).easyPaginate is not a function
>       at myJs.js:20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare scripts in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/myJs.js"></script>
```

As the error says, `easyPaginate` method can't be found in `myJs` script.

Comment: It is also recommended to put the scripts at the bottom of the page, so you don't "block" the browser.